# Unable to install Numpy on AWS EC2 Python 3.6

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux and a virtual environment with python 3.6.

I can't seem to install Numpy :

```
(testenv) [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx venv]$ pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.13.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.13.3

(testenv) [ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx venv]$ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Nov  2 2017, 19:34:31) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I also did a `sudo python36 -m pip install numpy` it did not work.

Comment: How about `sudo python -m pip install numpy`? What you posted should make your `python36` executable work, but it's not clear to me that `python` refers to the same one.

Comment: I get `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` It's installed for previous version of Python but not for 3.6 which is the one I use on this virtual environment...

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem and found a solution that worked for me on that website : https://samsblogofthings.wordpress.com/2016/07/17/installing-numpy-on-your-amazon-ec2-instance-for-a-particular-python-version/

Basically do :

`alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'`

and then :
`sudo pip3 install numpy`

Comment: This `pip3` in place of the `pip` I was using (to install `scipy`-- very analogous to `numpy`) did the wonder for me !  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo yum install numpy
```

Comment: I'm running Amazon Linux, and doing `sudo yum install python3-numpy` results in `No package python3-numpy available.`

Comment: Try `sudo yum install numpy` or `sudo yum install python-numpy`

Comment: Doing `sudo yum install numpy` installed numpy for Python 2.7. But in my virtual environment with Python 3.6 it still not shows.

Comment: `sudo yum install python3-numpy`

Comment: I tried as well, got a `No package python3-numpy available.`

Answer (score 0):

source your virtual environment and try to install numpy without sudo via pip from that env. It should work.

Comment: That's what I did, you can see on my post the `(testenv)` meaning I had sourced it already.